# What does cvHaarDetectObjects() method do?

Tags: java, image-processing, opencv, javacv

Please can some expert person explain me whether we can use the **cvHaarDetectObjects()** method to detect squares and get width and heights? I found a code that use this method for face-detection but I need to know whether I can use it for rectangle detection.

```
    String src="src/squiredetection/MY.JPG";
    IplImage grabbedImage = cvLoadImage(src);
    IplImage grayImage    = IplImage.create(grabbedImage.width(),  grabbedImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvCvtColor(grabbedImage, grayImage, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, cascade, storage, 1.1, 3, 0);//*
        for (int i = 0; i < faces.total(); i++) {
            CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem(faces, i));
            cvRectangle(grabbedImage, cvPoint(r.x(), r.y()), cvPoint(r.x()+r.width(), r.y()+r.height()), CvScalar.RED, 1, CV_AA, 0);
         /*   hatPoints[0].x = r.x-r.width/10;    hatPoints[0].y = r.y-r.height/10;
            hatPoints[1].x = r.x+r.width*11/10; hatPoints[1].y = r.y-r.height/10;
            hatPoints[2].x = r.x+r.width/2;     hatPoints[2].y = r.y-r.height/2;*/
          //  cvFillConvexPoly(grabbedImage, hatPoints, hatPoints.length, CvScalar.GREEN, CV_AA, 0);
        }
```

when I use above method it throws following exception

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Invalid classifier cascade) in unknown function, file C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\haar.cpp, line 1036
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\slave\WinInstallerMegaPack\src\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\haar.cpp:1036: error: (-5) Invalid classifier cascade

    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects(Native Method)
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_objdetect.cvHaarDetectObjects(opencv_objdetect.java:243)
    at squiredetection.Test2.main(Test2.java:52 I have put * on this line)
```

Please be kind enough to give simple code example for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cvHaarDetectObjects()` is used for detecting objects or shapes not only for faces, it depends on `HaarCascade` classifier.

If you pass `face haarcascade xml` then it will return an array of faces or also can use `eye`, `nose`, etc HaarCascade XML file. You can make also custom `haarcascade xml` by creating your own positive and negative samples using `opencv_traincascade.exe`

```
CvSeq faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(grayImage, classifier, storage,
                1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

for (int i = 0; i < faces.total(); i++) {
   // its ok
}
```

detail on [opencv doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html)

for rectangle detection :

> there is an example for rectangle detection in `OpenCV`, they use it to detect
>   the squares in a chessboard. Have a look to `squares.c` in
>   ..\OpenCV\samples\c\ directory.

see this [chessboard detection sample in opencv](http://www.code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/entry/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/squares.cpp)

*Invalid classifier cascade in unknown function* error means the classifier you passed is not correctly formatted or something is missing. Check if your classifier xml file is valid.

Answer (score 2):

`cvHaarDetectObjects` returns multiple faces detected in an image. You have to declare an array of CvSeq to store the result, not just a single CvSeq.

```
// There can be more than one face in an image.
// So create a growable sequence of faces.
// Detect the objects and store them in the sequence
CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects( img, cascade, storage,
                                    1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                    cvSize(40, 40) );
```

The code above was extracted from this site:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

Comment: Is that mean that it can't use to detect rectangles isn't it??

Comment: That's not the problem because in javacv we can assign it without error. I check javacv doc and it(cvHaarDetectObjects() method) returns only CvSeq. When I try to add array or linklist for that, it throw compile time error saying incompatible type.

Comment: Did you download binaries (already compiled to your system version) of OpenCV or compile sources in your system?